# FineUploader get uuid after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

How can i get the uuid of an image by clicking on it AFTER upload.
See the attached image.

[image]

I have found the following html line in my template:

```
<li class="qq-file-id-2 qq-upload-success" qq-file-id="2" style="">
```

I add an onClick-Event

```
<li onclick="selectFile(this)" class="qq-file-id-2 qq-upload-success" qq-file-id="2" style="">
```

And i get the qq-file-id by following code

```
function selectFile(vali){
            var imageIndex = $(vali).attr('qq-file-id');
            alert('Image Index is ' + imageIndex)
}
```

Instead of the qq-file-id i need the uuid. 
Where can i obtain this IN MY TEMPLATE after Upload?

`getUuid (id)` works only in a callback like `"onDelete"`.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Is the uuid stored somewhere in the DOM?  How does the onDelete callback access the uuid? Also, it is bad practice to integrate your javascript code into your html code.  Html is good for the layout and structure of the page.  Js is good for the logic and actions on the page.  Css is good for the design.

Comment: No, it isn't stored in the DOM. This is the question: How can i get the uuid of fineuploader in the DOM? I know how to continue when I have it in the DOM. But i don't know how i get the information about uuid AFTER upload placed in my html-template. Thanks for the information about bad practice. It's only for testing reason... I will consider your referrals. Thank you!

Comment: @Pippo, did you ever work this out? I need the UUID too. Please share if you worked it out. Thanks. 